# How to request querysting when using not ? and &

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

Sometimes people are using links like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.asp?id=12345&name=codehungry
```

And sometimes this:

```
http://www.example.com/12345/codehungry
```

I know how to request the querystring of the first link, like this way:

```
Request.Querystring["id"] or Request.Querystring["name"]
```

But how can I request the querystring from the second link? Which looks much cleaner!

Comment: The 2nd example doesn't have a query string.

Comment: How can I retrieve data from the database when using the 2nd example? For example SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name = Querystring. In the second example is the name: codehungry

Comment: You need to learn about routing.

Comment: To follow up on @SLaks advice, here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Normally I do something like: string Name = Request.Querystring["Name"]; SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FirstName = Name. If I rewrite my URL's, can I still get the name out of the friendly url, to retrieve data from the database?

Answer (score 1):

A querystring is anything after a ? (question mark), so the second URL has no querystring. If you're not using a framework with a routing component, then you'll have to parse the URL manually, which probably won't be much fun. Both ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC support routing; or perhaps you could derive some value from the Url Rewrite (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) software or ASP.NET FriendlyUrls.

Comment: Normally I do something like:
string Name = Request.Querystring["Name"];
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FirstName = Name.

If I rewrite my URL's, can I still get the name out of the friendly url, to retrieve data from the database?